# Is 'auto a_class::f(...) -> T const' ambiguous in the grammar?

Tags: c++, c++11, trailing-return-type

How should the below member function prototype be interpreted in C++11?

```
class C {
 public:
  auto f(...) -> T const;
}
```

It would seem to me that it could either be a const member function of the class C, or a non-const member function which returns a const value of type T.

I know I could just write the function as

```
T const f(...);
```

or

```
T f(...) const;
```

However, I want to be consistent with how I declare functions, so I decided to use the new C++11 `auto f(...) -> RetType` way everywhere.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The trailing-return-type comes *after* cv- and ref-qualifiers of a non-static member function. This means the example in the question is the same as `T const f(...);`.

`§8.4.1 [dcl.fct.def.general] p2`

> The declarator in a function-definition shall have the form
>
> `D1` ( *parameter-declaration-clause* ) *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub> exception-specification<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> trailing-return-type<sub>opt</sub>*

To declare a `const` member function, you'd write `auto f(...) const -> T const;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I wonder how the voting pattern will change if the names of people asking as well as answering were kept hidden.