# using c++11 auto as return type for const function object

Tags: c++, c++11, tbb, boost-graph

I have a const function object and for the timebeing, it returnes void. but can return int or double. I am writing the code in c++11 style and was just trying to use auto as return type. Although the code compiles, I am not sure it is 100% correct or not. Here is the code.

```
template <typename graph_t>
 struct my_func { 
   public:
    my_func() {  } 
    my_func (graph_t&  _G) : G(_G) {  } 

   template <typename edge_t>
   auto operator()(edge_t   edge) -> void const {

     //do something with the edge.
   } //operator

   private:
    graph_t& G;
   };

   //call the functor: (pass graph G as template parameter)
   std::for_each(beginEdge, endEdge, my_func<Graph>(G));
```

this code compiles and works in serial mode perfectly. Now I try to parallelize the above for_each using intel TBB parallel_for_each(). This requires the function object to be const. meaning the threads should not be allowed to modify or change the private variables of function object.

```
   //tbb::parallel_for_each
   tbb::paralle_for_each(beginEdge, endEdge, my_func<Graph>(G));

   Now, the compiler error comes: 
   passing const my_func< ... > ..  discards qualifiers
```

So I had to change the operator()() to the following:

```
   template <typename edge_t>
   void operator()(edge_t  edge) const { 

   // do something

   } //operator
```

My question is:  how do i use "auto operator()() ->void"   and also make the operator "const" so that it becomes valid ?

Comment: Put the "const" before the arrow ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14015173/481267

Comment: `auto operator()(edge_t edge) const -> void`

Comment: You don't *have to* use trailing return types just because you *can*!

Comment: Why would you write `auto foo() -> void`? Trying to win an obfuscation contest? Or to get a coworker to punch you in the face?

Comment: He probably doesn't want to rewrite it later, once he actually makes use of the trailing return type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is 'auto a\_class::f(...) -> T const' ambiguous in the grammar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015142/is-auto-a-classf-t-const-ambiguous-in-the-grammar)

Comment: @Pogo I'm always wondering what the hell are you doing? This project sounds so cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: how do i use "auto operator()() ->void" and also make
>   the operator "const" so that it becomes valid ?

```
   template <typename edge_t>
   auto operator()(edge_t   edge) const -> void
   {

     //do something with the edge.
   }
```

Remember, the declarator with a cv-qualifier has basically the following form:

( *parameter-declaration-clause* ) ***cv-qualifier-seq*** [*ref-qualifier*] [*exception-specification*] [***trailing-return-type***]

(Omitted the attributes)